# Prove $\frac{\sin A \cos A}{\cos^2 A - \sin^2 A} = \frac{\tan A}{1-\tan^2 A}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would I simplify this difficult trigonometric identity:

$$\frac{\sin A \cos A}{\cos^2 A - \sin^2 A} = \frac{\tan A}{1-\tan^2 A}.$$

I am not exactly sure what to do.

I simplified the right side to

$$\frac{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}{1-\frac{\cos^2 A}{\sin^2 A}}$$

But how would I proceed.

Comment: Use $\sin 2A= 2\sin A \cos A$ and 
$ \cos 2A= \cos^2 A- \sin^2 A$.

Comment: I will say all the post were helpful and I would give everyone recognition were I a registered user.

Comment: James, you can up/down vote on all posts (question, answers, comments) here (except your own ;-). Additionally you can choose among the given answer and accept the one that suits you most. Read the [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information. And last: Welcome to Math.StackExchange.com...

Comment: @draks, the ability to upvote requires 15 rep, which James had had for only about 2 minutes when he posted that comment. Quite possibly he hadn't noticed yet. _Downvoting_, on the other hand, requires 125 rep.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ah right, sorry, I forgot.

Answer (score 3):

$$RHS = \frac{\tan A}{1-\tan^2 A} = \frac{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}{1-\frac{\sin^2 A}{\cos^2 A}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}{\frac{\cos^2 A - \sin^2 A}{\cos^2 A}}\cdot \frac{\cos^2 A}{\cos^2 A}$$
$$=\frac{\sin A \cos A}{\cos^2 A - \sin^2 A} = LHS$$

Comment: A perfectly explained solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your error lies in how you simplified the right hand side (the denominator specifically).  Try again!  Turn $\tan x$ into $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ with $\displaystyle\tan x =\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$.

Now,
$$\frac{\tan{x}}{1-\tan^2{x}}=\frac{\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)}{1-\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^2}$$
You can multiply an expression by 1 and not change the value, (Since $1\cdot a=a$).  Now, the problem is *which* 1 do you multiply by?

You can achieve this by multiplying and distributing by $\displaystyle \frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}$.

Comment: I see I wrote it like that in my paper and now I have (sin/cos)/(1-sin^2/cos^2) but I am still stuck.

Comment: these identities are sometimes difficult but you can always simplify the strategy for solving them into two steps: 1) Turn everything into $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, and 2) Look for Pythagorean Identities (i.e. $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, $\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$, $\cot^2x+1=\csc^2x$)

Comment: And the Pythagorean Identities part can be expanded to include
$\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x=(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)$.  Anytime you see things like that try to find a Pythagorean identity

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sin 2A= 2\sin A \cos A$ and 
$ \cos 2A= \cos^2 A- \sin^2 A$ to get
$$
\frac{\sin A \cos A}{\cos^2 A- \sin^2 A}=\frac{\sin 2A}{2\cos 2A}=\frac12\tan{2A},
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
  \frac{ \tan A} {1 - \tan^2 A} .
$$

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-.2C_triple-.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) for reference.